# Monte Carlo error propagation

Tags: standard-error, monte-carlo, error-propagation

Consider a set $X$ of $N$ [iid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_and_identically_distributed_random_variables) random variables, each one with its own standard deviation:

$$X: \{x_1\pm\sigma_1, x_2\pm\sigma_2, ..., x_N\pm\sigma_N\}$$

Say I have a "black box" numerical function which *only* accepts the means of each variable, ie: $\{x_1, x_2, ..., x_N\}$. This function outputs a single value, which I call $y_{m}$.

The black box is not able to use the standard deviations of each variable in the $X$ set to estimate the uncertainty associated with $y_m$. **But I need to estimate an uncertainty for $y_m$.**

I thus apply a Monte Carlo process in this way:

1. Draw a random value for each variable in the $X$ set, assuming a normal distribution with mean $x_i$ and standard deviation $\sigma_i$. This generates a new "random set" $X_1$.
2. Process $X_1$ with the black box, and store the result: $y_{1}$.
3. Repeat points 1. and 2. $M$ times. The result is a set $Y$ of $M$  "black box values": $Y:\{y_1, y_2, ..., y_M\}$
4. Calculate the mean and standard deviation of $Y$: $\bar{y}\pm\sigma_y$.

My understanding of this process is that for a large enough $M$ then $\bar{y}\to y_m$ and $\sigma_y$ can be assigned as the standard deviation of $y_m$.

Is this assumption correct?

**Add**:

Can I assign $\sigma_y$ as the standard deviation of $y_m$ even if I can't prove that $\bar{y}\to y_m$?

Comment: It might be helpful to contemplate a simple example of such a black box, such as one that outputs the reciprocal of the first component of $X$. Consider what happens when (a) the random variable $x_1$ really is Normal and (b) when it does *not* have a Normal distribution. Different failure modes for your process are associated with these two possibilities.

Comment: I'm sorry @whuber but I can't follow your comment. Are you saying that the assumption that $\bar{y}\to y_m$ as $M$ gets larger is only valid under certain conditions?

Comment: That's right: and I believe you can readily discover those conditions by considering such simple, specific cases. In some cases $\bar y$ converges, but not to $y_m$; and in others it cannot converge at all.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification @whuber. What are then the conditions that the black box function needs to meet to ensure that $\bar{y}\to y_m$ assuming that the random variables in the $X$ set follow a true normal distribution?

Comment: They are almost circular and therefore practically useless. Your "black box" is known as a "measurable function" $T$ and your process is the one contemplated by the [Weak Law of Large Numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeakLawofLargeNumbers.html). Thus, you need to ensure that the expected value $\mathbb{E}(T(X))$ exists, that it equals $T(x_1,\ldots,x_N)$, and that $T(X)$ has a (finite) variance. That is very nearly a restatement of the desired conclusions--but the careful attention to existence and to the variance are clues about what can go wrong and why.

Comment: Thanks again @whuber. I've seen such a method applied liberally to numerous problems where these conditions were never addressed. I guess it's just a matter of the researcher assuming "$T(X)$ meets all necessary conditions" by default. I've added another related question to the post, would you mind telling me what you think?